# Manually instantiating components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting to integrate "some" Vue in a website I'm working on, and I have this case where I have a dialog, as a component, that lists files. By clicking on the "delete" icon next to the file, a new dialog pops up, where use can confirm whether to delete that file.

The way I've built it is I've got a root component, which has a child "dialogListFiles" (hidden by default, gets visible when user does a certain action), which itself programatically creates a new instance of "dialogConfirmDeletion" when user wants to delete a file.

This instantiation is done through a method in dialogListFiles :

```
deleteFile: function(fileInfo) {
    var DialogDeleteClass = Vue.extend(clDialogDeleteFile);
    var delDialog = new DialogDeleteClass({
        propsData: { 'fileInfo': fileInfo}
    });
    delDialog.$mount('#mountingPoint');
    this.visible = false;
}
```

#mountingPoint is a  within the template of dialogListFiles

Getting the deletion confirmation dialog to pop-up works fine. However:

- I can't get *$emit* to work: if I call *$emit* in a method of dialogConfirmDeletion, I don't manage to catch this event anywhere
- I've read [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/156) that "From a usage perspective, it is not recommended to manually mount inside another component's DOM", so I'm wondering if what I'm doing is just completely wrong, and if it is, what the right design should be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use the `confirm(msg)` method, like so:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) { this.visible = false; }
```

This will make a pop-up which returns `true` if the user accepts, which i think is what you are trying to achieve.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Well - that's the spirit of what I'm trying to achieve yes, but looking to use a more elaborate UI, hence creating a new dialog component for that

Comment: Ok. I missinterpreted your question. So, a component (the delete confirmation dialog) with the file you're trying to delete as input isn't enough? Or maybe a hidden component, which gets shown when clicked, for each of the files?

Comment: The component is enough indeed, but my question is about the design I should pick to do that. I wanted to avoid having a "hidden" components that gets shown when clicked and though I would just instantiate it when needed, and then destroy it - but 1. so far I haven't managed to handle events emitted from that component and 2. I've read (link in original post) that this isn't a good practice, so I'm looking for explainations as to why this is bad, and what the good way to do is

Comment: I understand and I can agree that manually mounting inside another's component DOM is not ideal, but I'm not the creator of Vue, so i won't write my thoughts. I'm sorry i couldn't help you and i hope you find an answer, and if so, post it here, please!